# Remote data service: speed concern

Tags: networking, http, database, remote-access

I would like to provide an online service that consists of the following:

1. A proprietary database
2. Queries to the database that not only ask for data, but more importantly sophisticated calculations on this data that are run on the same server that hosts the database

This service will be provided to a limited number of people(let's say 300) that I previously identified and authorized. These people actually run their own websites on their own servers. It is these servers that will send queries to my data-service.

The information-flow will thus be the following:

I.  End User A sends URL request to website-server B

II.  B identifies that this request needs data from my service C and thus issues a request to C

III.  C identifies the request, gets data from database, makes calculations, and sends CSV or HTML content back to B

IV.  B integrates data information with its own HTML design and send back an HTML response to A

V.  A receives HTML and displays it in a browser

-----In a few words: (A to B to C and back from C to B to A)

My main concern with this setup is that there might be a noticeable delay to the end user A because his/her request gets serviced by two servers in different locations.

My questions are:

- Do you know if there is a name for this type of setup(makes it easier to google, among other things)
- Are there any existing websites or web services that work like this
- Is my main concern(speed to service the end user's request) a real concern, or is it something that can be solved by:

  - Replicating data service(C) in several different locations so that each server B sends request to geographically closest C
  - Using a fast communication protocol(HTTP or FTP or other??)?

Any other comments or suggestions are very welcome....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that majority of websites on the internet use this setup in one way or another and often they use more than one service like yours, so you are not unique (sorry :-). If you make your server to respond quickly enough and host it in the cloud or with a decent hosting provider you should be just fine.